# State of Web Components in Frameworks

Tags: angular, reactjs, vue.js, web-component

I would like to get the state of Web Components for the most used frameworks: **React, Angular and Vue.js**

1. Are Web Components supported?
2. Can I build Web Components with them?
3. Can I use the components(2.) within those frameworks e.g. React Web Components in Vue.js?

Comment: Why add angular tag?

Comment: @PhuongThuan Because it's still used by something like 20+% of all sites?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes All of these frameworks can use Native Web Components.
2. No, none of these frameworks can make a Native Web Component. They each have their own way of making a component that may or may not be directly compatible with the Native spec.
3. While is is possible to use an Angular component in React etc I would not advise it.

A native component can be written one and use everywhere. You *will* need polyfills for browsers that don't support the Native spec yet. But I have used them from IE11 up. And I have use well written native components in all 3 of your mentioned frameworks.

But if you write something that is no to the Native spec in any framework then it is best to continue to use ii in that framework. Crossing the framework boundary is expensive and often will have complications that may prevent them from working.

Answer (score 0):

Web components are framework-agnostic, they are supported natively in the web browser and they will work inside any other framework.

You can produce web components with Vue.js and Angular build tools, but it's not the best way to make web components. The right way would be by using something like https://lit.dev/.

For a good example of reusable and framework agnostic web components you can refer to this repo:
https://github.com/ing-bank/lion
It combines all possible best practices for making web components.

Also, it would be useful for you to read through this resource:
https://open-wc.org/

It will help you to get most of your questions answered.

TLDR:

1. Yes, wc are supported in all modern browsers
2. Yes you can build wc with frameworks, but it is an anti-pattern
3. Yes, you can use wc within any framework